# How do I add a 7 cell wide row with the same formatting and formula as selected cell/row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet [https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrVB.png] that I need a bit of help with.

I have a new row button that I would like to be able to add a row of seven cells underneath the bigger table only. This new row should have the same formatting as the active cell/s and if possible should also carry the formula of the Total Fee column. Then at the end of the function I've made it turn a custom colour.

To be honest, I have no knowledge of vba at all but have come up with the below. It kind of works the way I want it to however the trouble is that the formatting ends up not being confined to the main table and spills over into the smaller tables on the right as pictured (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3pV4.jpg)

````
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Range("E1:K1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("E1:K1").Interior.Color = RGB(223, 49, 28)

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("E1:E1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore the option of "finding" the last row in this table - `lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` - and then copy/pasting Range("E1:K1") into the row below it `lrow + 1`. I'm not entirely sure what Offset does in this scenario.

Then, see if you can do both `xlpasteformulas` and `xlpasteformats` - there's not an [enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) that combines these two options.